# How can I calculate a distance matrix between columns only?

Tags: r

I have 10,000 proteins as columns and each have a expression value.

```
        A  B C D E F 
Value  0.1 3 4 5 6 10

I would like to calculate  the matrix as

  A B C D E F
A 
B
C
D
E
F
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `dist` like below

```
> x <- c(A = 0.1, B = 3, C = 4, D = 5, E = 6, F = 10)

> as.matrix(dist(x))
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A 0.0 2.9 3.9 4.9 5.9 9.9
B 2.9 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 7.0
C 3.9 1.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 6.0
D 4.9 2.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 5.0
E 5.9 3.0 2.0 1.0 0.0 4.0
F 9.9 7.0 6.0 5.0 4.0 0.0
```